# NHibernate QueryOver , JoinAlias problem

Tags: nhibernate, c#-4.0, queryover

I'm pretty new to Nhibernate and QueryOver techniques. Peace if I'm asking some basic things ;)

My hbm looks like this,

```
<class 
    name="ElementLogic.Wms.Common.Core.Orderline,Domain" 
    table="ORDERLINE" 
    lazy="true" 
    dynamic-insert="true"
    dynamic-update="true"
    >

 <many-to-one
      name = "Product"
      class = "ElementLogic.Wms.Common.Core.Product, Domain"
      access="field.camelcase-underscore"
      cascade = "save-update"
      fetch="select"
      insert = "false"
      update = "false"
      property-ref = "ExtProductId">
      <column name="EXTPRODUCTID" />
    </many-to-one>

 <property type="int" name="UserId" column="[USERID]" />

</class>
```

I'm trying to join entities as follows , which works fine

```
 query.JoinAlias(() => _orderLineAlias.Product, () => _productAlias);
```

I just want to know if I can join the User entity in the same way, without having to alter the **UserId** feild to a many-to-one relationship. Is it possible to acheive? if so pls be patient to explain :)

/BB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be no way around this problem. So I went ahead and added the mapping User to the OrderLine. ;)

/BB